# Can´t access to GCP instance after edit sshd_config

Tags: ssh, cloud, google

I have edited the sshd_config file of my instance (Google Cloud Platform) to change port 22 to a new port.
Add a new firewall rule for the port, but now I can't connect
neither to 22 or to the port that I have configured. Nor can I access through the serial port.
Anyone know any alternative to access the instance, or any option to
not lose all my settings (databases, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Create an ingress VPC firewall rule to allow the different ssh port.

Snapshot the broken instance's disk. Start a backup from this snapshot, just in case. Create a new disk from this snapshot and 
attach it as an additional disk to a working VM.

On the temporary instance, mount the copy of the broken disk. Edit sshd_config and any host firewalls. Test the sshd_config by starting another daemon with `sshd -f`.

Restore the fixed disk to an instance.

Comment: Thanks a lot... Do you have any tutorial for these ?